# apend text if class exists jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append text to a `p` element if a class exists. I would have been sure the below would work, but for some reason `$(this)` is being read differently to what I would have expected. Perhaps it is due to how the jQuery is set up.

I would like the `p` text to read `Test This is gone`

When I view `$(this)` in the console it is showing the object that the function is in.

I have **html** that looks like this

```
<div class="place-holder">
    <p class="place gone">Test</p>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var app = app || {};
!function(){
    app.test = {
        init: function ( ) {
            if($('.place').hasClass( "gone" ) ){
               console.log($(this));
               $(this).append('This is gone');
            }
         }
    }

 $(document).ready(app.test.init);
}(jQuery);
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is

Comment: i know! weird! i am confused as to why... is it because i used `hasClass`?

Comment: It's because `this` is function scoped, it doesn't magically become an element on the next line without a function

Comment: ah lovely! makes sense! tbh, i did think it was some magic jquery thing, but when i think to how `this` works in general this makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to do:

```
$('.place.gone').append('This is gone');
```

Also, if the input could possibly be malicious (Containing HTML), you should use `document.createTextNode()` to append:

```
$('.place.gone').append(document.createTextNode('This is gone'));
```

`$(this)` usually refers to the element that you're working with, but in this case, you're trying to get `this` from the init function (Which, since we don't know the caller, I'm unsure of what it could be.)

I think you're probably thinking about something like this:

```
$('.place').forEach(function() {
    //In this case, forEach assigns the element to the 'this' variable.
    if ( $(this).hasClass( "gone" ) ) {
        console.log($(this));
        $(this).append('This is gone');
    }
}
```

Comment: clever! i like it! still wanna know why `$(this)` is different to what I think!

Comment: @phantom without being a mindreader, we cant know "what you think".

Comment: thanks brilliant answer, and @Jamiec i never expected anyone to be reading my mind. FrankerZ has answered the question perfectly and hit the nail on the head

Answer (score 0):

Unless the text you are appending should have HTML, you should use

```
$('.place.gone').append(document.createTextNode('Hello World'));
```